CUDA graph cudaKernelNodeParams kernelParams
I want to use CUDA Graph in my CUDA project, but there aren’t many complete examples online. So, I directly referred to the official API to implement it, but I keep encountering a segmentation fault. Could you help me take a look?
To better control the entire flow of the graph, I chose to use the CUDA Graph API instead of the stream capture approach. The following code can reproduce the issue directly.
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

__global__ void mdl(int *n_out, const float *eigen_vals, int n) {
    __shared__ float shm[8];

    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    float threshold;

    if (tid < n) {
        shm[tid] = eigen_vals[tid];
        __syncthreads();

        if (tid == (n-1)) {
            threshold = shm[tid] * 0.01;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0;i < n;++i) {
                count += (shm[i] >= threshold) ? 1 : 0;
            }
            *n_out = count;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    int *d_object_n;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_object_n, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemset(d_object_n, 0, sizeof(int));

    thrust::device_vector<float> d_eigen_values{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8};
    int n_ant = 8;

    cudaGraphNode_t nodeMDL;
    cudaGraph_t m_graph;
    cudaGraphExec_t m_graphExec;

    cudaGraphCreate(&m_graph, 0);

    cudaKernelNodeParams nodeMDL_param = {0};
    nodeMDL_param.func = (void*)mdl;
    nodeMDL_param.gridDim  = dim3(1);
    nodeMDL_param.blockDim = dim3(8);
    nodeMDL_param.sharedMemBytes = 0;
    nodeMDL_param.extra = nullptr;
    

    void* args[] = { &d_object_n, (void*)(d_eigen_values.data().get()), &n_ant };
    nodeMDL_param.kernelParams = args;

    cudaError_t err = cudaGraphAddKernelNode(&nodeMDL, m_graph, nullptr, 0, &nodeMDL_param);

    err = cudaGraphInstantiate(&m_graphExec, m_graph);
    if (err != cudaSuccess) { 
        std::cerr << "Failed to cudaGraphInstantiate: " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
    }

    err = cudaGraphLaunch(m_graphExec, 0);
    if (err != cudaSuccess) { 
        std::cerr << "Failed to cudaGraphInstantiate: " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


Please do proper CUDA error checking: What is the canonical way to check for errors using the CUDA runtime API?

With (void*)(d_eigen_values.data().get()) you are passing the device pointer while the CUDA runtime expects the host pointer to the device pointer (as OP has correctly passed for d_object_n). Just adding the missing & causes a compilation error though, as d_eigen_values.data().get() is a temporary/rvalue. The solution is to create a local variable holding the device pointer and taking the address of that local variable:
auto const d_eigen_values_ptr = d_eigen_values.data().get();
void* args[] = { &d_object_n, &d_eigen_values_ptr, &n_ant };

As these C-APIs are not type-safe, it is easy to mess this up.

The main problem in your code is this below:
(void*)(d_eigen_values.data().get())

because data().get() returns the raw pointer contained in a device_ptr. But, you need device pointer here, which is d_eigen_values.data().
The complete work version is this below:
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/host_vector.h>

__global__ void mdl(int* n_out, const float* eigen_vals, int n) {
    __shared__ float shm[8];

    int tid = threadIdx.x;
    float threshold;

    if (tid < n) {
        shm[tid] = eigen_vals[tid];
        __syncthreads();

        if (tid == (n - 1)) {
            threshold = shm[tid] * 0.01;
            int count = 0;
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                count += (shm[i] >= threshold) ? 1 : 0;
            }
            *n_out = count;
        }
    }
}

int main() {

    int* d_object_n;
    cudaMalloc((void**)&d_object_n, sizeof(int));
    cudaMemset(d_object_n, 0, sizeof(int));

    float data[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 };
    thrust::device_vector<float> d_eigen_values(data, data + 8);
    int n_ant = 8;

    cudaGraphNode_t nodeMDL;
    cudaGraph_t m_graph;
    cudaGraphExec_t m_graphExec;

    cudaGraphCreate(&m_graph, 0);

    cudaKernelNodeParams nodeMDL_param = { 0 };
    nodeMDL_param.func = (void*)mdl;
    nodeMDL_param.gridDim = dim3(1);
    nodeMDL_param.blockDim = dim3(8);
    nodeMDL_param.sharedMemBytes = 0;
    nodeMDL_param.extra = nullptr;

    void* args[] = { &d_object_n, &d_eigen_values.data(), &n_ant };
    nodeMDL_param.kernelParams = args;

    cudaError_t err = cudaGraphAddKernelNode(&nodeMDL, m_graph, nullptr, 0, &nodeMDL_param);

    err = cudaGraphInstantiate(&m_graphExec, m_graph, NULL, NULL, 0);
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to cudaGraphInstantiate: " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
    }

    err = cudaGraphLaunch(m_graphExec, 0);
    if (err != cudaSuccess) {
        std::cerr << "Failed to cudaGraphInstantiate: " << cudaGetErrorString(err) << std::endl;
    }
    int object_n;
    cudaMemcpy(&object_n, d_object_n, sizeof(int), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
    std::cout << "result = " << object_n << std::endl;

    return 0;
}

The output:
result = 8


"you need device pointer here" Why? The kernel takes a raw pointer as it's argument and the raw pointer is still pointing to device memory.

@paleonix, you misunderstood cuda doc. Where did you ever see that “kernel takes a raw pointer” in any official cuda doc?

You are trolling (or trying to use an LLM that has no clue). Kernels take raw pointers as long as you define them to do so. OPs kernel signature has a raw pointer, not a Thrust wrapper.

As the wrapper has only the raw pointer as data member, it would not be suprising for this change to (still) work as these APIs are not typesafe. But I'm certain that you didn't solve OPs issue. If you can't replicate it, maybe it has nothing to do with the code and his CUDA installation is broken.

A raw pointer pointing to device memory is still a "device pointer" which is needed (which might be what confuses your LLM). As the thrust::device_ptr wrapper is part of the Thrust library and not of the underlying CUDA Runtime API, it makes no sense for the Runtime API to be asking for this wrapper.

You don't seem to have verified your own fix, as that code does not compile because your are trying to take the address of an rvalue. Fixing the rvalue issue makes it work (as I have alluded to above) and it keeps working after extracting the raw pointer. Feel free to correct your answer. Your code already contains the actual solution, which was adding the missing & to get the (host) address of the device pointer. I'm not after your internet points. But I don't like keeping this plain wrong answer around.
